# Loop through column names and put them into variables. ASP

Tags: variables, loops, asp-classic

I need to be able to loop through column names and put the coloumn name and it's value into a variable. My code looks like this.

```
SQL = "select column1, column2 from table1"
set rs = conn.execute(SQL)

For each fld in rs.fields
    fld.name = rs(fld.name)
Next

rs.close
```

But this is not working. How can I loop through the column names and set them as variables without having to specify each column name?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should use [GetRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx) method. Returns a two-dimensional array. You don't need column names through GetRows.
Consider this:

```vb
SQL = "select column1, column2 from table1"
set rs = conn.execute(SQL)
arrRecs = rs.GetRows
For row = 0 To UBound(arrRecs, 2) 'Rows
    For col = 0 To UBound(arrRecs, 1) 'Columns
        Response.Write rs.Fields(col).Name & " = " & arrRecs(col, row) & " "
    Next
    Response.Write "<br />"
Next
rs.close
```

Comment: This is fine, but I need to place the values returned into variables so I can reuse them on my page.

Comment: If that is the case, then just add a line to create a dynamic name for the variable based on the loop count:  THISPASS = "varname_" & col
and then set that variable on each pass so you can call the variable with varname_1 or varname_2 for the second one and so forth .. im building something just like this right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the field names, you can use Dictionary and have each field name as a key, then the values of each column as array.

First, declate the dictionary:

```
Set oData = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Now populate it with data using those two loops:

```
For Each fld In rs.Fields
    oData.Add fld.Name, Array()
Next

Do Until rs.EOF
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        tempArray = oData(fld.Name)
        ReDim Preserve tempArray(UBound(tempArray) + 1)
        tempArray(UBound(tempArray)) = rs(fld.Name)
        oData(fld.Name) = tempArray
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

And finally, you can show all the column names using such code:

```
Response.Write("Column names:<br />")
For Each fld In oData.Keys
    Response.Write(fld & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
Next
Response.Write("<br />")
```

Or show the values for specific column:

```
Response.Write("Values for column named Id:<br />")
If oData.Exists("Id") Then
    tempArray = oData("Id")
    For x=0 To UBound(tempArray)
        Response.Write(tempArray(x) & "<br />")
    Next
Else  
    Response.Write("Such column does not exist")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code above, and store the name/value pair in session, like session("table." & fieldname) = rs(fieldname). I use it a lot for storing user, customer, supplier, etc., information. Works like caching too. You can create sub routines like reloadCustomer(customerNumber) to reload. That way you aren't going to the DB for basic info. Update it when changed...

Dictionary object:

```
set dic = server.createobject("scripting.dictionary")
dic.add "keyName1", "Michael"
dic.add "keyName2", "John"
dic.add "keyName3", "Steve"

dic.Item("keyName2") <-- gives you "John"
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I can't use sessions as I will be implementing Web Garden with IIS. I need to be able to store these values in standard variables and reuse them locally within the page.

Comment: In that case, I would say to use Dictionary object. However, I used to come across bugs that when I grabbed a key, it would remove it as well--not sure if that was by design, or a bug. See above...